# Get the value of a variable from another process via Python

Tags: python, memory, process, ctypes

There is a task - to get the values of some variables from the game Dota 2 in Python, specifically this is the data of the choice of heroes by allies and enemies, on the screenshot - the top bar with the icons of the heroes. When a player chooses a character, the empty window above the nickname is replaced with the icon of the selected hero. This choice I need to track through the process. Next, on the set of id of the heroes, a ready algorithm will tell you which character is most advantageous in this draft (a set of heroes of allies and enemies).

[image]

Are such operations possible with processes through Python? If, for example, I allocated a set of addresses to these variables and just want to receive data, how do I implement it? Addresses are dynamic, so they need to add the value of the shift to what I understand, and I do not understand much of these shifts, addresses. I use the Cheat Engine to view memory, Python 3.6 on Windows.

Comment: No offence, but it seems that you are not nearly capable of doing that with your current knowledge. You have to learn more about it, but stackoverflow is not a place to learn things like that... Come back here when you have some code which does not work the way you'd expect it to.